# package convention for java Springboot lightweight controllers?

Tags: spring-boot, coding-style, standards, java-package

We have the controllers already being used with many apis in the package

```
com.mycomp.myapp.controllers
```

The controllers developed are heavy, so planning to add light weight apis with minimum request parameters.

confused between these two
`com.mycomp.myapp.controllers.lite` or `com.mycomp.myapp.lite.controllers`

Can anyone suggest the package names with conventions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should go with **com.mycomp.myapp.controllers.lite**.
Because actually you are creating controllers only and now controllers would be distinguished by light or heavyweight. That's why the distinguishing part should be inside the controller package.

Happy coding :)